# What is the range of psi abilities?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I just got my first gifted (a sniper); it seems Mind Fray doesn't benefit from squad sight. (Which does make sense.)
But I was wondering, at what range can psionic abilities be used?

Other reading suggests there aren't any bonuses or penalties for range/cover/defense.
Do psi-abilities have the same range as normal attack abilities?
Do all psi-abilities have the same range?

Comment: So many questions could be split up into separate questions to make answering your questions easier.

Comment: @Paralytic They are not separate questions, they're clarifications of the title-question "What is the range of psi abilities?" In spite of the clarifications, the only answer given was incomplete. So I decided to edit in the additional information before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 3 aggressive psi-abilities, like normal attacks, can be targeted at any enemy that the psi-user can see. This means that they must be within the same range as for normal attacks (27 internal units, or 17-18 grid cells) and they must have line of sight.

Unlike normal attacks, psi-abilities are not affected by cover or defense. Instead, their chance of failure is related to the Will values of the attacker and the defender.

The 2 defensive psi-abilities have no range, they're simply centered on the psi-soldier. So bear this in mind when positioning soldiers to use those abilities.

Comment: Sight radius and normal weapon range are 27 internal units, or 17-18 grid cells. [Related discussion](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90424/what-do-distance-units-mean).